# How to make overflow-y: hidden; work on click with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to make sure that on click my menu will be opened and for `body` it will add CSS option, which is overflow-y:hidden` in order to focus users' attention on menu only. So whenever user clicks menu button it will appear, and will not have that scroll that annoys users, however when menu closes it scroll obviously should work. How to achieve it ?

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $('.slide').fadeToggle(500);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        console.log('click');
        $('.darklayer').toggleClass('active');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        var dark = '.darklayer';
        $(dark).toggleClass('active');
        if ($dark.is(':active')) {
            $('body').css({
                'overflow-y': 'hidden'
            });
        } else {
            $('#button').css(off);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#main_header {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#main_header .text_ru {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgb(12, 89, 163);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18px;
  height: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

p.text_ru {
  line-height: 1.929;
}

#main_header .left_header {
  float: left;
}

#main_header .right_header {
  float: right;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

.darklayer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.35;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.darklayer.active {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 768px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="main_menu">
  <div id="menu">
    <ul class="slide">
      <li><a href="#">Поиск строения</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Оплатить ком услуги</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Обратиться за помощью</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Управляющая компания</a></li>
      <li><a href="second_page.html">Обратиться в Акимат</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Объявления</a></li>
      <li><a href="page.html">Информация о строении</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Обсуждения</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Помощь</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <section id="main_header">
    <div class="left_header">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="svg/logo.svg" alt="logo" style="height: 16px; padding-left: 15px;"></a>
      <p class="text_ru">ru</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right_header">
      <img class="btn search" src="svg/search.svg" alt="search" style="height: 18px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 30px; cursor: pointer; ">
      <img class="btn" src="svg/pro.svg" alt="pro" style="height: 18px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 30px; cursor: pointer;">
      <img id="button" class="btn" src="svg/sandwich.svg" alt="sandwich" style="height: 18px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 30px; cursor: pointer;">
    </div>
  </section>
</header>
```

Comment: `.css('overflow-y', 'hidden');` or pass object `.css({'overflow-y': 'hidden'});`

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet. You can now easily see the syntax error which appears in the console and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Use this .     **$('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');**

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan now I refactored my code and now I want that it will catch an event when user clicks and stops the scroll and when it closes it should work again

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var dark = '.darklayer';
        $(dark).toggleClass('active');
        if ($dark.is(':active')) {
   $('body').css({'overflow-y': 'hidden'});
   } 
   else { $('#button').css(off); }
 });
});

Comment: Please use the `edit` button to update your question. Code in comments is pretty much unreadable

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I will do it now

Answer (score 0):

You can use it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
  });
});
```

Comment: I think some explanation of code or logic help other community members to understand what you are trying to do here. So please add explanation with your answer.