# Why does my button cannot disable overflow-y:hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve that my button will be responsive. In precise, on first click when menu opens it darkens the entire screen and highlight the menu, as well as `overflow-y:hidden`starts working since my goal is to make sure when menu opens it won't have any scroll. There when the main issue starts to appear, overflow hidden takes place and I cannot switch off when I click on menu button again.
How to achieve this ?

my previous jquery:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
        $('.slide').fadeToggle(500);
        $('.darklayer').toggleClass('active');
        $('body').css({'overflow-y': 'hidden'});
});
```

here is my new jquery:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
        var $dark = $('.darklayer');
        $('.slide').fadeToggle(500);
        ($dark).toggleClass('active');
            if($dark.is(':active')) { 
                $('body').css({'overflow-y': 'hidden'});
            }
            else {
                $('body').off('click');
            }
    }});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="darklayer"></div>
    <header id="main_menu">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul class="slide">
                    <li><a href="#">Поиск строения</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Оплатить ком услуги</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Обратиться за помощью</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Управляющая компания</a></li>
                    <li><a href="second_page.html">Обратиться в Акимат</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Объявления</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">Информация о строении</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Обсуждения</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Помощь</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <section id="main_header">
                <div class="left_header">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="svg/logo.svg" alt="logo" style="height: 16px; padding-left: 15px;"></a>
                    <p class="text_ru">ru</p>
                </div>
                <div class="right_header">
                    <img class="btn search" src="svg/search.svg" alt="search" style="height: 18px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 30px; cursor: pointer; ">
                    <img class="btn" src="svg/pro.svg" alt="pro" style="height: 18px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 30px; cursor: pointer;">
                    <img id="button" class="btn" src="svg/sandwich.svg" alt="sandwich" style="height: 18px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 30px; cursor: pointer;">
                </div>
            </section>
        </header>
```

Comment: Nukezhan, it don't look like you even changed you code from your previously question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996858/how-to-make-overflow-y-hidden-work-on-click-with-jquery

Comment: Remove excess `}` from your javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: user `hasClass` as shown below

```
$("#button").click(function(){
        var $dark = $('.darklayer');
        $('.slide').fadeToggle(500);
        $dark.toggleClass('active');
            if($dark.hasClass('active')) { 
                $('body').css({'overflow-y': 'hidden'});
            }
            else {
                $('body').off('click');
            }
    }});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem in if statement you can use

```
if($dark.hasClass('active'))
```

instead of

```
if($dark.is(':active'))
```

Comment: Appreciate your support! my friend!

Comment: @NukezhanMontreal You're totally welcome you can vote me up and accept [Bhushan Kawadkar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/649504/bhushan-kawadkar) answer he posted one minute faster than me .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: I pleasantly did it !

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
        if($dark.is(':active')) { 
            $('body').css({'overflow-y': 'hidden'});
        }
        else {
            $('body').css({'overflow-y': 'visible'});
        }
```

Comment: Your welcome! You can upvote my answer if you want :)